# AngularJS - Using Directive in template

Tags: angularjs-directive

I have a question about custom directive.

Is it possible to

1. Create a custom directive
2. provide it with a templateURL attribute and
3. in template URL make the use of `ng-grid` attribute ?

I tried it although my grid is not getting rendered properly if declared in template. This is how my template code looks like

```
 <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions">
 </div>
```

and my controller code inside custom directive looks like

```
treeApp.controller('treeController',function ($scope, $http,TreeFactory) {
    console.log("calling controller");

TreeFactory.getTreeData().success(function(data){

    $scope.myData = data;
    $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };
});;
```

and this is how my custom directive looks like

```
treeApp.directive('ngTree', function(TreeFactory) {
 return {
  restrict: 'A',
  require: '^ngModel',
  templateUrl: 'js/angular/templates/ngtree-template.html',
});
```

Comment: Are you still interested in an answer? All these things are not only possible but AngularJS basics.